# How to rotate cropped images in single canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, gsap

I have drawn a single image inside canvas, that is cropped into 4 different pieces. I would like to rotate, for example, the second cropped region around its top most side at the center. 
Right now, if I change the `translate` values, the rotation is the same as before, only difference is that the `posX`, `posY` are changed.

**Drawing function:**

```
//Function that is called on each 'tick' event, 60fps
draw: function(){
    if(this.rotation != 0){
        _self.elements.context.save();      
        // what values to put here so that '2' would rotate correctly ???
        _self.elements.context.translate(0,0);      
        _self.elements.context.rotate(this.rotation);
        _self.elements.context.drawImage(
            _self.elements.image,this.sx, this.sy, this.sw, this.sh, this.dx, this.dy, this.sw, this.dh
        );
        _self.elements.context.restore();
    }else{
        _self.elements.context.drawImage(
            _self.elements.image, this.sx, this.sy, this.sw, this.sh, this.dx, this.dy, this.sw, this.dh
        );
    }
}
```

**Rotation using TweenMax**

```
//Rotate the '2' cropped image part   
TweenMax.to(_self.CanvasImages.collection[1], 2, {rotation:0.5});
```

I have also provided full code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t24ya3kc/11/) which should bring a greater understanding of what exactly I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have been able to understand this correctly, here is what I think you can do:

1. In your line with **`_self.elements.context.drawImage(...`** call inside **`draw`** function within the **`_self.CanvasImage`** object,    instead of passing **`this.dx`** and **`this.dy`**, try passing    **`0`** and **`0`**.
2. And then in your **`_self.elements.context.translate(...`** call    inside the same function, pass **`this.dx`** and **`this.dy`**.
3. This should rotate the object around its **`top-left`** point.
4. However, if you want to move it around its **`top-center`** point
   then what you can do is in the same
   **`_self.elements.context.drawImage(...`** call mentioned above, instead of passing **`0`** as a replacement to the previous
   **`this.dx`** value, pass **`-(this.sw * 0.5)`**.

***JS Code Update #1*** (for points 1-3 above):

```
...
_self.elements.context.translate(this.dx, this.dy);
_self.elements.context.rotate(this.rotation);
_self.elements.context.drawImage(_self.elements.image, this.sx, this.sy, this.sw, this.sh, 0, 0, this.sw, this.dh);
...
```

***[jsFiddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/5pwu5yds/)***.

***JS Code Update #2*** (for point 4 above):

```
...
_self.elements.context.drawImage(_self.elements.image, this.sx, this.sy, this.sw, this.sh, -(this.sw * 0.5), 0, this.sw, this.dh);
...
```

***[jsFiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/5pwu5yds/1/)***.

Hope this helps.